# dismiss view controller to another view swift 3

Tags: swift, segue, viewcontroller, dismiss

is there any way to dismiss the current view without going to the view that the user was previously on but to a different one that I could specify? 
thanks for any help.

Comment: Please clarify the question, do you mean that a viewcontroller is presented and you want to dismiss the current viewcontroller from somewhere else in your code?

Comment: no I mean that i want to dismiss the current view controller but not go back to the last one. i want to chose which one it goes to

Comment: are you using `UINavigationController`?

Comment: no ia am not. is that bad if so can you explain what I should do

Answer (score 0):

If you embed your current viewcontroller (vc1) in a navigation controller (nc) and want to move to viewcontroller 2 (vc2) you can do the following:

on vc1:

```
self.navigationcontroller.present(vc2, animated: true)
self.dismiss(animated: false)
```

This will present the second viewcontroller and in the background remove the vc1.

Forgive me my pseudocode I dont have a mac close right now.